# Trigger azure synapse pipeline only when multiple events hit event grid topic?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-eventgrid

I am using Azure Synapse and want to trigger a pipeline only when certain number of events occur. I referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-custom-event-trigger and was able to trigger a pipeline when 1 event is pushed to the event grid topic.

**But is there a way to trigger the pipeline only when >1 events are pushed to event grid topic ?**

Example:

event E1 is published to event grid at 10am ||
event E2 is published to event grid at 11am

I want my synapse pipeline to be triggered at/after 11am.

Answer (score 0):

The requested feature is not built in the Azure Event Grid. The following screen snippet shows an example how can be done using the Azure Stream Job in the generic manner:

[image]

As the above picture shows, the events (E1, E2, etc.) are ingested into the destination resource such as the Azure Event Hub and then analysed by stream job for triggering based on the needs.

Comment: Does ASA have this capability to do 'AND' check? Meaning, can we check in an ASA job that do something only when both E1 and E2 events are available?

Also, what if I want 
E1+E2 -> trigger pipeline-1
E1+E2+E3 -> trigger pipeline-2

can it handle this as well ?

Comment: Yes, the ASA has a capability for analysing an event stream pipeline in the real-time with generating multiple outputs. More details can be found in the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/